# What was the point of the smoke in The Dark Knight Rises?

Tags: dc, batman, nolan-batman-trilogy, the-dark-knight-rises

During the first fistfight between Bane and Batman, midway through the fight Batman throws what look to be smoke pellets at Bane and whiffs completely on all of them:

1 minute and 30 seconds into this clip is a good reference.

What exactly was the point of that? I've seen stronger variations of smoke pellets used by Batman that are meant to literally blind the opponent and give you time to escape, but even from the camera work you can tell that Bane couldn't have lost vision from that and they were thrown so far off that he's have to be looking behind him to get anything from the effect.

Comment: Looks like Batman was attempting a desperate distraction, more to buy himself a little time while Bane was looking where the smoke pellets hit, which would have worked on most ordinary criminals.

Comment: @FerusOlin - It doesn't say in the novel or the script, but my guess is that they were all that Batman had to hand. They were never meant to be used as smoke-grenades...

Comment: Of course, if he'd pulled one of [these](http://www.impactguns.com/smith-and-wesson-642-airweight-38spp-1-78-inch-fixed-sights-glass-bead-rubber-grips-5rd-163810.aspx) out of his belt, he could have shot Bane in both kneecaps and both elbows and still had a bullet left over. I know Batman is no fan of guns, but get over yourself, dude.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They were supposed to distract Bane, buying Batman some time to think of a new plan. Suffice to say, they didn't work.

> This wasn’t going well…
>   Bane clambered after him, swinging down on a chain, while his men watched in disciplined silence, enjoying the duel. **Hoping to buy some time, Batman plucked a handful of miniature flash-bangs from his Utility Belt and flung them at his pursuer. The charges went off like firecrackers, producing a disorienting barrage of sparks, noise, and smoke.
>
>   Yet Bane didn’t even flinch.**
>
> <sub><sup>[The Dark Knight Rises: Official Novelisation](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/13536475-the-dark-knight-rises)</sup></sub>

Comment: Whelp, that was anticlimactic. They're just tiny firecrackers and poor framing.

Comment: @GGMG - I didn't remember them being quite so...puny. Bad show, Batman :-)

Answer (score 2):

It was an attempt at disconcerting Bane. After throwing those pellets Bane remarked that "***theatricality and deception [were] powerful agents to the uninitiated***". Throwing smoke pellets at an enemy could instill confusion and possibly even fear in one's opponents. This is what Batman was *trying* to accomplish. Unfortunately, they were initiated, weren't they GGMG? Both members of the League of Shadows.